# How to Sculpt Toothpaste or Paint Coming Out of Tube?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I need to create blobs of paint on a palette that look like they've been squeezed out of a tube. Here's an example:

[image: https://www.uncommongoods.com/images/items/26700/26788_1_640px.jpg]

Any suggestions on how to model those blobs of paint?

Comment: yeah sculpting its a way to do it

Answer (score 2):

just like this using a cube with dyntopo sculpting. [image]

Comment: Thank you. Here's another image: 

https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/red-paint-blob-white-2915277.jpg

I'm having an issue getting the edges right where it meets the surface it's on. In this second image, you can see that there's this slightly bulging, surface tension effect where it meets the surface it's sitting on.